# Paypal IPN: my domain suffix appears twice

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am setting up my IPN for PayPal its been tested using a send box account and the site worked.

Now that I have gone live I am testing using real money and the ipn set up is

```
www.mysite.co.uk/XXXXXXXXX
```

However when I make the payment I notice in the url reply on my browser and when I check the IPN history on Paypal it says `www.mysite.co.uk.co.uk. The`.co.uk` appears twice. I assume this is the reason I am not getting the orders finalised on my backend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be programming related, as stated in the [help/on-topic]. Please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal/info) for more information and helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can specify the IPN listener URL:

1. your PayPal profile, or
2. with your transaction

It's very likely to be caused by mis-configuration in either of the two places.

If you specified it with your transaction, depending on the product you use, you may be able to find it in a parameter similar to "notify_url" or "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL". You'd need to refer to the documents of the product you are using.